# How can I read in M-bus metering data with an Arduino Uno?

Tags: c, io, protocols, arduino, meter

I am trying to send data from a Kamstrup Multical 601 to an Arduino Uno using the [M-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter-Bus) protocol.

I am considering trying to use the [libmbus c libraries](https://github.com/rscada/libmbus) to do this. However, I do not have a lot of experience in c programming so was wondering if:

- you think this is a realistic/achievable approach?
- anyone could suggest an alternative/easier approach?

The main chip on the Arduino Uno is the Atmel Atmega382P-PU.

After getting the data to the Arduino I aim to perform some calculations and send data to an LCD (this I think I can do).

Answer (score 3):

On the [Arduino Website](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Libraries) there is a short how-to about the use of external C-Libraries with Arduino.

Note that you cannot simply connect M-Bus with a RS-232 interface. There is a so called "level-shifter" device necessary inbetween to do the "electrical transition". See the EN 13757-2 standard doucment for what this device is exactly doing with the signal. Without such a [device](http://www.m-bus.com/files/minimaster.tif) you won't get any word out of your M-Bus device.

Answer (score 0):

The library you link to appears to be for Linux. The Arduino, of course, doesn't run Linux so a library won't compile for it directly.

You should probably try implementing the library yourself, but using the Arduino's standard libraries to access ports and so on.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is not clear but re-writing/porting the libraries is what I meant in the question - it seems like a daunting task at the moment!